# Sharing clock pulse between different devices

Tags: digital-logic, clock, level-shifting, schmitt-trigger, cascade

[image]
I have an application where i want to use the external clock signal (around 1kHz) with my microcontroller. I am interested in positive edge of the clock which will be detected by microcontroller. I also want to be able to keep "boosting" this clock so that another circuit (another copy of same circuit) can re-use the same clock signal if needed (like cascading ).

My solution: "Design 1" where I just send the inverted clock signal from schmitt trigger (HCT14M) output (1Y) to two of its inputs (2A & 3A). One of the output (2Y) will be used by my microcontroller and another output(3Y) can be used as "Clock Out" for external circuits.
I am using this schmitt trigger because:

1. The External CLOCK OR ENABLE pulse can be greater than 5V,( max around 10V). Hoping the 20K/100K series resistor will limit the input current <20mA and will be accepted by the schmitt trigger. This will also act as voltage translator. Datasheet mentions that ["The input and output voltage ratings may be exceeded if the input and output current ratings are observed."](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct14.pdf?ts=1682304823232). Since Input/output clamp current is 20mA, I guess this is okay??
2. I also want to use this schmitt trigger to maintain the CLOCK shape when being shared with other circuits and it'll also act to "boost" it for cascading.

However, I saw another circuit (Design 2) which essentially is using the CLOCK sharing like I just mentioned. It used the same Schmitt trigger. However instead of just passing the inverted CLOCK pulse (1Y) to another schmitt trigger input, it seems they sent the inverted clock signal through a capacitor (unsure about its value). Then used 100k pullup resistor and another 100K resistor in series before sending it to the schmitt trigger input. Finally used this output for cascading. From what I know, you can add capacitor in series to use as edge detector. Also one of the 100K resistor is being used as pullup so that the output is normally LOW. Which makes sense. I guess.. I want to understand this setup as a whole.

My questions:

1. How is "Design 2" CLOCK boost circuit better? is it better than my simple Design 1 ?
2. Using series resistors 100k,20K for ENABLE & CLOCK signals will it allow me to use higher voltage signals (>Vcc) as input sources to my schmitt trigger ? if so, what happens to the "HIgh level" and low level input voltages. Will they remain the same or will it change depending on the input voltage levels?

Answer (score 0):

> Since Input/output clamp current is 20mA, I guess this is okay??

20 mA is the **absolute maximum** clamp current, which is *not* OK. However with 20 kΩ in series the injected current is less than 0.25 mA at 10 V, which should be OK. Just remember that this current is injected into the power supply. If for any reason current draw on the 5 V line drops below ~0.30 mA (total injected current of the two EXT inputs) the voltage could rise, possibly causing misoperation or even blowing up sensitive devices.

> How is "Design 2" CLOCK boost circuit better? is it better than my
> simple Design 1 ?

As a straight clock buffer it's no better, and possibly worse (depending on the capacitor value). The designer must have had a reason to do it that way for their particular application, but we can only guess what it was (pulse width shaping, failsafe, ???).

Incorporating random elements into a design without knowing their purpose is generally not good practice. Even if it is for a similar application you could be copying something inappropriate to your implementation. You only need a clock buffer, so just do that.

> what happens to the "HIgh level" and low level input voltages. Will
> they remain the same or will it change depending on the input voltage
> levels?

The high/low switching voltage levels will stay the same. The only difference is if the maximum input voltage is higher then the switching levels as a proportion of it will be lower. For digital inputs that shouldn't matter so long as they meet the required high/low voltages.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by “  If for any reason current draw on the 5 V line drops below ~0.30 mA (total injected current of the two EXT inputs) the voltage could rise, possibly causing misoperation “ also how do i safeguard against it?

Comment: The input is pulling up to eg. 10V. The 5V regulator in your power supply doesn't pull down, so without a current sink the voltage can rise above 5V and the regulator can't stop it. One way to prevent it is put a 5V zener diode across the input.